# SwiftUI How to Disable Button While Uploading Objects in an Array

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI form where the user adds images to an array from a picker and then a function fires to upload each image.  The images are displayed in a ForEach as either an upload spinner while the upload is happening OR the actual image once the upload has completed.

I'd like the NEXT button, which would remove the user from the view, to be disabled until all of the uploads have completed.

I'm not sure how to inform the State of the Parent View that all of the uploads are completed.

Here's what my Parent View looks like:

```
struct ProjectFormStep4: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var authVM: AuthorizationClass
    @EnvironmentObject var projectVM: ProjectsViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var uploadVM: UploadManager
    
    @ObservedObject var mediaItems = PickedMediaItems()
    
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var showUploadView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
            ZStack{
                Color("BrandGrey").ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Button{
                            projectVM.showProjectFormStep1 = false
                            projectVM.showProjectFormStep2 = false
                            projectVM.showProjectFormStep3 = true
                            projectVM.showProjectFormStep4 = false
                        } label: {
                            Text("< Back")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("BrandLightBlue"))
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 30)
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color(.white))
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                            .cornerRadius(12)
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("BrandLightBlue"))
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(height: 60)
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        self.showSheet = true
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                        PhotoPicker(mediaItems: mediaItems) { didSelectItem in
                            showUploadView = true
                            showSheet = false
                        }
                    })
                    Spacer()
                    ScrollView{
                        
                        ForEach(uploadVM.uploadedMedia, id:\.id){ item in
                            ImageArea(
                                item: item,
                                items: uploadVM.uploadedMedia
                            )
                        }
    
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    if showUploadView {
                        ForEach(mediaItems.items, id: \.id) { item in
                            UploadView(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Next")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                            .background(Color("BrandOrange"))
                            .cornerRadius(15.0)
                    }

                }.padding()
            }
    }
}
```

Here's my Child View of which handles the upload spinner and actual image:

```
struct ImageArea: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var projectVM: ProjectsViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var uploadVM: UploadManager
    @State private var showThumbnailOptions: Bool = false
    var item: UploadedMedia
    var items : [UploadedMedia]

    var body: some View {
        
        if item.secureUrl == "" {
            ZStack{
                
                UploadSpinner()
                    .frame(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 200
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(12)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading ){
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(
                                width: 30
                            )
                        Image(systemName: self.getWaterMarkName(item: item))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                            .padding(4)
                            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(item.uploadProgress)%")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.body)
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }

                    }
            }
        } else {
            ZStack{
                ProjectRemoteUploadImage(projectImageUrl: projectVM.standardizeThumbnail(thumbnailUrl: item.secureUrl))
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showThumbnailOptions.toggle()
                    }
                if showThumbnailOptions {
                    Color(.black).opacity(0.8)
                    VStack{
                        Spacer()
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.backward.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .padding()
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    self.showThumbnailOptions.toggle()
                                }
                            Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .padding()
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    deleteThumbnail(
                                        item: item
                                    )
                                }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    
    func getWaterMarkName(item: UploadedMedia) -> String {
        if item.mediaType == "photo"{
            return "photo"
        } else if item.mediaType == "video" {
            return "video"
        } else {
            return "photo"
        }
    }
    
   func deleteThumbnail(item: UploadedMedia){
       let itemID = item.id
       guard let itemIndex = uploadVM.uploadedMedia.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == itemID}) else { return }
       uploadVM.uploadedMedia.remove(at: itemIndex)
    }
}
```

Adding model info for the uploadedMedia

```
struct UploadedMedia {
    
    var id: String
    var uploadProgress: Float
    var secureUrl: String
    var mediaType: String
    var width: Int
    var length: Double
    

    init(
        id: String,
        uploadProgress: Float,
        secureUrl: String,
        mediaType: String,
        width: Int,
        length: Double
    ){
        self.id = id
        self.uploadProgress = uploadProgress
        self.secureUrl = secureUrl
        self.mediaType = mediaType
        self.width = width
        self.length = length
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to tell because there's a lot missing for this to be a [mre], but it seems like you'd want to base the disabled state on something like `uploadVM.uploadedMedia.allSatisfy { !$0.item.secureUrl.isEmpty }`. But, it's not clear whether the items are setting a published property and are observable from the view, so that's pretty speculative.

Comment: @jnpdx I'm thinking I'd have to check if any of the item objects contain an empty secureUrl element?  Or one equal to the initialized value which is ""

Comment: Right, that's what I'm suggesting in my code sample

Comment: @jnpdx so     var uploadCompleted: Bool {
        if uploadVM.uploadedMedia.allSatisfy({ $0.secureUrl != "" }){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

Comment: Seems reasonable, but again, since it's not testable for me, I'm not sure. What happened when you tried it? By the way, your could shorted that code to `var uploadCompleted : Bool { uploadVM.uploadedMedia.allSatisfy { !$0.item.secureUrl.isEmpty } }`

Comment: @jnpdx thanks.  gives me something to play around with.  I have a few button states to control and this is one of them.